# update to 16.10 doesn't work after restarting the computer

Tags: 16.10

I've updated using software updater but it downloaded some stuff and restarted my machine but the update didn't take effect(Still running on 16.04) and when i try to update again it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04LTS will only upgrade to another LTS edition unless you set in your Software & Updates in System Settings for Updates to go to Any Newer Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your settings for updating. Change "Only for new LTS" to "for every new version". Then update and try what happens.